# Was bedeutet die Abkürzung "beh. konz."?

Tags: vocabulary, abbreviation, austrian

### Was bedeutet diese (offenbar österreichische) Abkürzung?

Im internet finden sich zwar die folgenden Beispiele, aber keine Erklärung:

> Immobilien Krammer Günter Krammer beh. konz. Immobilienmakler
> <sup>([yelp](http://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=realestate&find_loc=2225+Zistersdorf))</sup>

---

> Bruckner Leonard R beh konz Immobilienverwaltung Nfg Brigitte Mategka-Bruckner
> <sup>([vienna.net](http://www.vienna.net/company/vienna/property-management/bruckner-leonard-r-beh-konz-immobilienverwaltung-nfg-brigitte-mategka-bruckner-226.html))</sup>

---

> JOH. W. ZOLL, Beh. konz. Häuser- u. Gebäudeverwalter, Wien <sup>(historisches Dokument, datiert 1940)</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

beh. konz. = behördlich konzessionierte(r)

Jemand ist behördlich konzessioniert, wenn er eine behördliche Genehmigung zur Ausübung eines Gewerbes hat.

Comment: gibt es auch eine ähnliche Bezeichnung im "Standartdeutsch"?

Comment: @vogel vielleicht *akkreditiert*?

Comment: Nein, eine Akkreditierung ist nicht das gleiche wie eine Konzession. Es gibt auch im deutschen Verwaltungsrecht den Begiff der Konzession und es gibt konzessionspflichtige bzw. genehmigungspflichtige Gewerbe (de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konzession). Nur käme ein deutscher Taxifahrer wohl nicht auf die Idee, "behördlich konzessionierter Taxibetrieb" auf seine Visitenkarte zu schreiben.

Comment: @Vogel612: Das ist Standarddeutsch. Es gibt drei Standards für die Deutsche Sprache: Deutsches Deutsch, Österreichisches Deutsch und Schweizerisches Deutsch. Das sind Standards, die an Schulen gelehrt werden. Das Amtsdeutsch des jeweiligen Landes ist Teil eines jeden Standards. »Behördlich konzessioniert« ist also schon allein deswegen Standarddeutsch, weil dieser Begriff von einer Behörde in amtlichen Urkunden verwendet wird.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it just means "licensed". You didn't ask, but "Nfg" means Nachfolger, i.e. successor.